# What is the correct NGINX configuration for OJS?

Tags: php, nginx, ojs

I hardly find solution of Nginx configuration of my OJS server.

I try to run php 8 to run OJS with ubuntu 22.04.2. Been try [How to run Open Journal System (OJS) on Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227530/how-to-run-open-journal-system-ojs-on-nginx) and no result.

Right now this is my Nginx conf :

```
server {

    root /home/bappeda/public_html;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/ejournal.deliserdangkab.go.id.log error;
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name ejournal.deliserdangkab.go.id;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ejournal.deliserdangkab.go.id/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ejournal.deliserdangkab.go.id/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    
    }

location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
     set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
     fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $path_info;
     fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED         $document_root$path_info;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     include fastcgi_params;
 }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

}
server {
    if ($host = ejournal.deliserdangkab.go.id) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    server_name ejournal.deliserdangkab.go.id;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Any help on this will be truly appreciated!

Comment: Nope. But I use the latest version of OJS, and it working now.